# Add drop-down to group header in Kendo UI for Angular Grid

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

At the moment I have developed a Kendo UI Grid with grouping as shown in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/jjvubysAmQKeuQI86bHx?p=preview

template as follows

```
<kendo-grid
    [kendoGridBinding]="gridData"
    scrollable="none"
    [group]="groups">
    <kendo-grid-column
      *ngFor="let column of customColumnList"
      field="{{column.field}}"
      title="{{column.title}}">
      </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="" title="Education Level">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
            <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="performanceListData"[value]="'Select Education'">
            </kendo-dropdownlist>
          </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="" title="Salary package">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
              <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="measurePackageData" [value]="'No'">
              </kendo-dropdownlist>
            </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
  </kendo-grid>
```

[image: plunker at the moment]

I need to add a drop-down to each group header so that when I select a value from that, all grouped values will be updated. I have tried to add as a custom table but then the UI of the group template does not align with the table.

[image: need drop-downs for each group header with for each column]

Any suggestions to achieve this?